# Browserify - disable closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, closures, browserify

I have recently started using *Browserify* but I've ran into one serious problem. I have an object of functions which I need to use in my HTML view. Simple example:

**js**

```
Menu = { open: { /* open menu */ } }
```

**HTML**

```
<span onclick="Menu.open()"></span>
```

I *need* to use it like this, the event listener is not working for this. I have tried to define menu as `window.Menu`, but that is not working either (for unknown reason).

So my question goes - is there any way to make variables accessible globally even in HTML views and dev console?

The only thing I can think about is completely removing the closure but I didn't find any way to do so.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the closure you are referring to?

Comment: Anyway, `Menu` inside the bundle is not going to be visible from the outside. Instead, what you should to is a `document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', Menu.open)` or equivalent in your JS.

Comment: Well, and that's my problem. The closure (I don't know the exact name) is a function around the whole code so all variables have the function's scope and aren't accessible globally. And what I need is either to give the variables inside global scope or completely remove the closure.

Comment: The "closure" you refer to is the bundle created by browserify. This is designed to be a self-contained bundle which runs the app. As I mentioned, there are (normally) no entry points within the bundle which you can access from outside, such as an `onclick` handler, which you probably should not be using anyway.

Comment: Within a Browserify bundle, you could expose a global like this: `global.Menu = { open: { /* open menu */ } }`. You can also control the exposing of modules using the `standalone` and `require/expose` options mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage).